# Full standard stream redirection without potential deadlock

Tags: c++, linux, io-redirection

If I want to redirect stdin, stdout, and stderr, without the risk of deadlock (for example, child process may need more data on stdin to flush stdout), do I have to spawn multiple threads, or is there any other solution to the problem. Current implementation:

```
std::thread stderr_proc{read, io_redirector.handle(), stderr, io_redirector.stderr()};
std::thread stdout_proc{read, io_redirector.handle(), stdout, io_redirector.stdout()};
write(io_redirector.handle(), stdin, io_redirector.stdin());

int status;
if(::waitpid(pid, &status, 0) == -1) { abort(); }

stdout_proc.join();
stderr_proc.join();
```

Including the main thread, this implementation uses one thread per stream to avoid deadlock, but I think it is quite heavy-weight to start two new threads. Especially since this is called from one of many worker threads, it would be nice to have a single-threaded solution.

Comment: Where do you want to redirect it to? If on Linux - maybe use `dup()`? `risk of deadlock (for example, child process may need more data on stdin to flush stdout` What do you mean by "child process may need more data on stdin to flush stdout"? How is that a deadlock? Don't you want to disable buffering then? `it would be nice to have a single-threaded solution.` If on Linux - why not use `poll`?

Comment: @KamilCuk Deadlock because parent process blocks on write (because the pipe is full). But yes, should probably look into poll or epoll

Comment: Just to note that [`boost::process`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/boost_process/tutorial.html#boost_process.tutorial.async_io) probably has most (if not all) of the functionality you're looking for.